# Repeated / Stretched Top Panel with Gnome Classic

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-panel, nvidia, gnome-classic

Has anyone seen something like what is shown in this screenshot (the back of the top panel is repeated before the panel itself is shown)? I'm using:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Switched to Gnome Classic
- Dual monitors
- Nvidia driver version current-updates (which is 280.13)

[image: Stretched top panel]

I'm posting this question here as opposed to Launchpad , because I'm wondering if anyone has seen something like this and have a good guess at what could be causing the stretching of the top panel.

The size of the panel is set to 24 pixels in "Properties" so it's not that.

The resolution of both screens is 1600 x 1200, so it's not that.

Any leads?

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I did. If you are using Gnome classic just do Alt + right click on any of those repeated panels and select "Remove". This will remove this panel. Do the same for all the repeated top panels. I am not sure if this will be permanent since I just tried it and I haven't restarted my computer. I hope it is though!